# Getting text from Table Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

Working on a web scraping project, and I'm having trouble getting some of the data in a uniform way. The page has a two-column table, and I need to only grab the text of the second column to run compile the values.

I'm working on it like this:

```
const rq = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

rq(url, (err, res, html) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('#table-id > tbody > tr > td.data').toArray().map(item => {
        console.log(item.text());
    });
});
```

But I'm getting an error that `.text()` is not a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.text()` is a **cheerio** method so to use it you need to make the item a **cheerio** element

this should work:

`console.log($(item).text())`

Answer (score 4):

You have to wrap `item` with `$()`, to convert it to a `cheerio` element.

```
$('#table-id > tbody > tr > td.data').toArray().map(item => {
  console.log($(item).text());
});
```

You can also use [.each](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#each-functionindex-element-) and drop `toArray` and `map`. And use `$(this)` to reference the current element.

```
$('#table-id > tbody > tr > td.data').each(() => {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```